# How can I put an interactive diagram inside of a Word (.docx) document?

Tags: c#, vba, controls, openxml, docx

I know this question may seem a bit vague, but I'm looking to output a .docx file (using Office Open XML) that contains an interactive diagram that can accept user input and use the entered data to update fields within the document.

I work as a Railway Design Engineer, and I'm experimenting with a system that will be able to automate some of what we do. The image below shows a typical front sheet for a component known as a Crossing...

[image: Crossing Front Sheet]

At the current time, the diagram is static (i.e. it contains no interactive elements), and can't be used with any VBA macros or anything else. The thing is, the values in the table below the diagram are determined by the values within the diagram, but we currently have to enter everything by hand.

So my question is, is there a way to insert a control to substitute this diagram(preferably written using C#) inside of a .docx file and make it easy to update the information within either externally (via Office Open XML) or internally (via VBA macros)? The thing is, whilst I want my system to initially generate the document, I want the user to be able to edit it outside of the program and have it automatically calculate the information within the table from the information within the diagram.

Comment: The issue with using Word for an application you describe is that MS Word has no provision to capture edit events within the document, unless you get down to the API level and capture individual keypresses. My suggestion is to create this as an Excel spreadsheet, complete with the drawing and table and calculations. It can very likely be done with no VBA at all. If you have to use MS Word as the main document, embed your spreadsheet as an object in the document - the user can still perform edits. (I worked on a track gang and we installed these many years ago, hard work and good memories :) )

Comment: Supplementing @PeterT 's remarks: What you describe would mean creating an ActiveX control using the .NET Framework. This is *not* trivial, there have been discussions on the topic in the MSDN VSTO forum, for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71a75dc4-dcea-454a-9e4a-011a2f811994/vsto-activex-and-powerpoint?forum=vsto For more, search ActiveX control Darst (Geoff Darst was the "guru" on the topic a few years ago).